# Select all or Unselect all in listbox using jquery?

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have asp.net listbox. first item of the listbox is "--All--". If user selected 1st item of the list then automatically select all items. If user unselect 1st item of list then automatically unselect all items. How can I do that using jquery?

```
    <asp:ListBox ID="lstDatabases" runat="server" Height="134px" Width="396px" SelectionMode="Multiple" >
</asp:ListBox>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
$("#selectId").on('change', function() {
    if ($(this).val() == "all") {
        $("select > option").prop("selected", true);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

jQuery: Select all options in a Multiple Select Listbox

```
$("#multipleselect option").prop("selected",true);
```

A multiple select listbox with everything already selected for you!

From : 
http://www.craiglotter.co.za/2010/02/26/jquery-select-all-options-in-a-multiple-select-listbox/