# Dropdownlist with "Select All" option in MVC3

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

So I hope the title says everything.

I want to create a dropdownlist with an "select all" option at the very top.
The problem is that I don't have a clue how to get started on this and was hoping someone could aid me in this quest. After some browsing, I couldn't find any good examples and decided to post this question here.

I don't know a lot about MVC yet, I'm still learning. Can't show you any code either, because like I said earlier, I don't have a clue on where to begin.

I'm not asking for the entire code sample, but rather an example of how you can do this and how to begin. That way I can learn from it and maybe do it myself, with the help of you guys.

Can you guys help a rookie programmer out and help me on my way?

Comment: Search for Dropdownlist or DropDownListFor helper

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, for one, `DropDownListFor` renders a single-select, so you can't use that and "select all", as it's not possible to pass all the items back with a single-select.

You *could* use `ListBoxFor`, which will generate a multiple-select. That will at least allow you actually select all, in the first place. However, there's no HTML method for selecting all items in a select list, so there is therefore no way for MVC to give you such a control, as it's a limitation of HTML. You can implement some custom JavaScript that would activate on a button click or something, and then programmatically select all the items in the select list. See: [Select all or Unselect all in listbox using jquery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14693593/select-all-or-unselect-all-in-listbox-using-jquery)

Comment: I tried this and so far, I managed to get a DropDownList (by using ListBoxFor). But the only problem is when I selected multiple items with jQuery, it doesn't pass the values to my server side code? I receive an empty list of values, even though all of them are selected in the list.

Comment: `SelectedId` would need to be something like `List<int>`. Make sure the type of the property is correct. The name seems to imply it's only an `int`.

Comment: That did the trick. My problem was that I initially made a new List<int> and forgot to take that part away. So I always initialized a new list over and over again.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to use the Html helper, `DropDownList` or `DropDownListFor` in MVC. You can provide these with a IEnumerable`.

So basically build up your Select List after adding your initial element which has a Key of 'Select All'

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedId, m.SelectList)
```

Where SelectedId is the property on your model that will contain the selected option on Postback, and SelectList is your list of SelectListItems .

```
var model = new TestViewModel();
model.SelectList = new List<SelectListItem>();
model.SelectList.Add(new SelectListItem(){ Value = "0", Key = "Select All" });
```

---

**Resources**

[ASP.NET Using the DropDownList helper](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions/working-with-the-dropdownlist-box-and-jquery/using-the-dropdownlist-helper-with-aspnet-mvc)

[MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492948(v=vs.118).aspx)